# How to change the visibility of a child view in onCreateView?

Tags: android

I know there are a lot of `setVisibility()` questions on here but I can't find any about this specific case.

When I set the visibility in onCreatView():

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parentfragment, container, false);

    View childView = view.findViewById(R.id.child_View)

    if(routingIsOn)childView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    else childView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    return view;
}
```

It doesn't change anything.  (I have hard coded the routingIsOn value as both true and false and either way it doesn't affect the view's visibility.

However interestingly if I run the `setVisibility()` code in a delayed runnable on the main thread it does update the UI as expected.  But this feels really hacky.

So is there a non-hacky way to change the visibility when the fragment is being created?

Here is the parent xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.salesrabbit.android.sales.universal.canvass.map.MapContainerFragment">



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/route_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/area_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Post ```fragment_parent.xml```

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos  I added the xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when something like this is happening, it is because the Android framework is automatically saving and restoring view state for you. I didn't think that visibility was part of the saved state, but maybe it is.

During `onCreateView()`, this state has not yet been restored, so anything you change that will later be restored will just be overwritten. You have to make your changes *after* the view state has been restored, and the callback to do that in is `onViewStateRestored()`. Try this:

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    View childView = getView().findViewById(R.id.child_View);

    if (routingIsOn) {
        childView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the "why this happens" explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val childView = view.findViewById(R.id.child_View)
    if(routingIsOn)childView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    else childView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
```